# regex - replace underscore lowercase with uppercase

Tags: java, regex

I've wondering is there a regex pattern that i could use to convert a pattern which is an underscore and a lowercase letter into an uppercase letter. I'm trying to generate fieldnames for a java bean from a SQL statement. At the moment the DB columns are

```
load_id,policy_id,policy_number
```

but i would like to the java field names to be

```
loadId,policyId,policyNumber
```

I've tried with this [regex fiddle](http://fiddle.re/gc9x4)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use:

```
String s = "load_id,policy_id,policy_number";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "_([a-zA-Z])" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( s );
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1).toUpperCase());
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString()); // loadId,policyId,policyNumber
```

Comment: +1 but `[A-Z]` seems redundant (at least based on OP title and examples).

Comment: I know but I just wanted to not miss the cases when it is like: `load_Id`

Comment: Fair enough. I will leave my comment anyway so OP would know that regex can be optimized a little if there will be no cases like `_Id` :)

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you want to use [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

**Code**:

```
import static com.google.common.base.CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL;
import static com.google.common.base.CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "load_id,policy_id,policy_number";
        for(String columnName : str.split(",")) {
            System.out.println(LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(LOWER_CAMEL, columnName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
loadId
policyId
policyNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this on regexp level you have to use `\U` to switch on uppercase mode and `\E` to switch it off. Here is an example how to use this feature in IntelliJ IDEA `find-and-replace` dialog which transforms set of class fields to JUnit assertions (at IDE tooltip is a result of `find-and-replace` transformation):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.common.base.CaseFormat;
```

```
protected static String replaceDashesWithCamelCasing(String input){
    return CaseFormat.LOWER_HYPHEN.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL, input);
}
```

Comment: `println(CaseFormat.LOWER_HYPHEN.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL, "load_id"))` gives you `Load_id`

Comment: it actually meant to be `CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, input)`